# Counting words in array

Tags: java

I'm trying to count words in an array. But it doesn't work.

My code:

```
public static int countWords(String input)
{
    char []a = input.toCharArray();
    int spaces = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
        if(a[i] == ' ')
            spaces++;
    return spaces + 1;  
}
```

What is the problem?

My input was `"stack over flow"`.

Comment: How does it "not work"? Is it giving incorrect amount of words? One immediate problem I see is that if you have two consecutive spaces, it won't recognise that.

Comment: What's the input string, what is the output and what would you expect the output to be ?

Comment: output says always 1. Because of the spaces+1.

Comment: Nope, I get the correct answer. What's the **input** you are testing it with?

Comment: Works for me too. If you are using some dynamic string as the function parameter, maybe look for the error there. `System.out.println(countWords("This is a test"));` correctly prints out 4.

Comment: Please post  how do you execute this function

Comment: @fbrozovic thanks a lot but i couldnt do it with an input from user.

Comment: @Niemand Thanks for your attention. I would take string from user.

Comment: Are you sure you are reading the right input string from the user? Did you try printing out the string just before counting the words to see if it's correct? I can't really think of anything else going wrong here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code counts the number of spaces and uses that to infer the number of words.

Unfortunately, this approach only works if there is exactly one space between each word, and no leading or trailing spaces.  It also assumes that there is only one kind of space character, and that's not true either.

(Aside: If you are reading text typed by a user, it is *unrealistic* to expect that they always put exactly one space between each word, and nowhere else.  Even if the specification says that they will / should do that.)

A simple but more robust alternative is to:

- trim the string to remove leading / trailing whitespace
- use String.split to split the string, supplying a simple regex for the "stuff between words"; e.g. `"\\s+"` says "one or more whitespace characters",
- return the length of the resulting array of words.

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with your code ? It looks to work fine here.

If your input string contains insecable space, you must handle this by testing his input code (160) :

```
if(a[i] == 160 || a[i] == ' ')
    spaces++
```